# Missing KVM nic model pcnet

Tags: kvm-virtualization, nic

I'm working on migrating a virtual machine from a centos6 server running qemu-kvm version 0.12.1 (qemu-kvm-0.12.1.2-2.503.el6_9.6) to an AlmaLinux8 server running qemu-kvm version 6.2.0 (qemu-kvm-6.2.0-20.module_el8.7.0+3346+68867adb.2) but I'm running into a problem getting the network interface to work. The VM was using the pcnet nic model, but that model is not available with the newer qemu-kvm version:

/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm -net nic,model=?
Supported NIC models:
e1000
e1000e
rtl8139
virtio-net-pci
virtio-net-pci-non-transitional
virtio-net-pci-transitional

This virtual machine is running SCO UNIX Openserver 5.0.5 so the supported nic cards are very old, and I don't believe I can use the available nic models. Is there some way to add the pcnet nic model that was available in other versions?

Comment: use Virtio network interface type, I don't see any reason to be forced to use the old one

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are able to add the old nic model from that previous version of KVM. Even if it were possible, this sounds like kicking the can down the road for the next guy to figure out when it will be migrated yet again.

Since you have a backup of the VM, I would try to use some of the NIC models available in that version of KVM.

SCO Unix Openserver is based on FreeBSD 10, I would also poke around the manual pages for more information on what is available.
https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ethernet&apropos=1&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+10.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html

You can compile these drivers into the kernel or update loader.conf to load the driver at boot time.

Rtl8139 -

https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rl&apropos=0&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD+10.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html

Virtio -

https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=virtio&sektion=4&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+10.0-RELEASE+and+Ports

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the qemu source here:
wget https://download.qemu.org/qemu-6.2.0.tar.xz

I built the qemu source with pcnet support. I then linked qemu-system-x86_64 to qemu-kvm and I was able to get the pcnet nic working. I don't know why the AlmaLinux8/RHEL8 version of qemu-kvm does not include the pcnet nic. It was included in CentOS7/RHEL7 and is included in Ubuntu 22.04.